# Realizar separação em uma Linha de dados e montar um array

Tags: php

Eu recebo de um GPS uma linha de dados como no 1º exemplo a baixo, e tenho que  trata-lo separando por virgula nos mesmo moldes do segundo exemplo:

1. Exemplo dados Originais

   ```
    (027043011394BR00160422A2242.5954S04237.5592W000.40056470.000000000000L00000000)
   ```
2. Exemplo como tem que ser a saida (SEPARAÇÃO POR VIRGULA)

   ```
    027043011394,BR00,160422,A,2242.5954S,04237.5592W,000.4,0056,70.0000,00000000L,00000000
   ```

E agora Montar um array

```
[0] => 027043011394 - ID (identificação do dispositivo) 
[1] => BR00 - comando 
[2] => 160422 - em DATE (o formato yymmdd) 
[3] => A -? 
[4] => 2242.5954S - o Latitude 
[5] => 04237.5592W - Longitude 
[6] => 000.4 - Speed (nnn.n format) 
[7] => 0056 - Time a (o formato hhmmssas a UTC) 
[8] => 470.0 - Designação / rolamento (?) 
[9] => 00000000L - a Elevation 
[0] => 00000000 -


$ID                         = $parts[0];
echo $comando               = $parts[1];
echo $date                  = $parts[2];
$A                          = $parts[3];
$lat                        = $parts[4];
$long                       = $parts[5];
$speed                      = $parts[6];
$time                       = $parts[7];
$eleleva                    = $parts[8];
$eleleva2                   = $parts[9];
```

Comment: Depois de colocar as vírgulas, basta usar a função explode pra criar o array com os dados. O problema está em colocar as vírgulas. Sabe dizer se esses dados são sempre do mesmo tamanho? Digo,  ID vai ser sempre com 12 caracteres e assim por diante?

Comment: Isso mesmo os tamanhos não mudam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) do PHP, para quebrar a String original. Ex:

```
  $array = [];           
  $array[] = substr($stringOriginal,0,12);   //Ou atribui logo em $id
```

E assim obter o primeiro valor, para pegar o próximo, você pode incrementar uma variavel, com o tamanho retirado da string:

```
  $pt = 0;
  $array[] = substr($stringOriginal,$pt,12);
  $pt+=12;
  $array[] = substr($stringOriginal,$pt,4);
  $pt+=4;
  ....
```

Ou, se preferir, você pode pegar só o restante da string, e utilizar zero sempre no segundo parametro.

```
    $array[] = substr($stringOriginal,0,12);
    $stringOriginal = substr($stringOriginal,12,strlen($stringOriginal)-12);
    $array[] = substr($stringOriginal,0,4);
    $stringOriginal = substr($stringOriginal,4,strlen($stringOriginal)-4);
    ....
```

Comment: Funcionou Perfeitamente aqui pra mim  obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Não tem muito segredo, como a formatação dos dados não tem um padrão a solução é extrarir pedaço por pedaço via substring, pelos intervalos definidos.

Use a função `substr()` para pegar o pedaço desejado da string o primeiro argumento é a string, o segundo o inicio da 'captura' e o terceiro o número de caracteres. E por último use `implode()` para formatar a saida como os valores do array separados por vírgula.

```
$str = '027043011394BR00160422A2242.5954S04237.5592W000.40056470.000000000000L00000000';

$info = array();
$info['id'] = substr($str, 0, 12);
$info['comando'] = substr($str, 12, 4);
$info['date'] = substr($str, 16, 6);
$info['A'] = substr($str, 22, 1);
$info['lat'] = substr($str, 23, 10);
$info['long'] = substr($str, 33, 11);
$info['speed'] = substr($str, 44, 5);
$info['time'] = substr($str, 49, 4);
$info['designacao'] = substr($str, 53, 5);
$info['eleleva'] = substr($str, 58, 12);
$info['eleleva2'] = substr($str, 70, 8);

echo implode(',', $info);
```

Outra solução seria definir dois arrays, o primeiro com a posição inicial de cada campo e o segundo com a quantia de caracteres a serem extraidos, nesse segundo exemplos as chaves do array serão númericas.

```
$inicio = 0;
$posicoes = [0, 12, 16, 22, 23, 33, 44, 49, 53, 58, 70];
$caracteres = [12, 4, 6, 1, 10, 11, 5, 4, 5, 12, 8];
$arr = [];

$i = 0;
while($i < 11){
    $arr[] = substr($str, $posicoes[$i], $caracteres[$i]);
    $i++;
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 027043011394
    [1] => BR00
    [2] => 160422
    [3] => A
    [4] => 2242.5954S
    [5] => 04237.5592W
    [6] => 000.4
    [7] => 0056
    [8] => 470.0
    [9] => 00000000000L
    [10] => 00000000
)
```

Comment: Na vi necessidade de outra resposta sugerindo também "substr", seria melhor concentrar teus esforços em resolver questões em aberto, do que repostar a mesma solução, de outra forma. Lembrando que sempre é possível editar uma resposta, caso julgue que algo esta inadequado, ou incompleto.

Answer (score -2):

Você poderia usar a função explode.

```
$var = explode(",", $texto);
```

Veja a documentação: [Função Explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)